# knockout template displays only the last value

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I created an element to calculate a division of the product price, it is created whenever there is a price for the product.

All calculation is successful, however in the value view template is displayed only the last calculation made, in the console the values are correct only in the template that does not bring the correct element.

Console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DR46.png)

Js:

```
     return Component.extend({

        defaults: {
            display: ko.observable(true),           
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.maxInstallments = ko.observableArray();
            this.getMaxInstallment();
            console.log(this.maxInstallments[0]);
        },

        getMaxInstallment: function(){
            var value_for_calc      = $(this.value_for_calc).val();
            console.log('price ' + value_for_calc + " for product id " + this.product_id);
            this.maxInstallments    = this.getInstallments(value_for_calc).slice(-1);
        },
        getInterest: function(){
            return this.interest;
        },
        getValueForCalc: function(){
            return $(this.value_for_calc).val();
        },
        getTypeInterest: function(){
            return this.type_interest;
        },
        getLimitByPlotPrice: function(){
            return this.limite_by_price;
        },
        getLimitByPortionNumber: function(){
            return this.limite_by_installment;
        },
        getInstall: function (value_for_calc) {
            var valor           = parseFloat(value_for_calc);
            var type_interest   = this.getTypeInterest();
            var info_interest   = this.getInterest();
            var min_installment = this.getLimitByPlotPrice();
            var max_installment = this.getLimitByPortionNumber();
            var json_parcelas   = {};
            var count = 0;
            json_parcelas[1] = 
                        {'parcela' : priceUtils.formatPrice(valor),
                         'juros' : 0
                        };
            var max_div = (valor/min_installment);
                max_div = parseInt(max_div);
            if(max_div > max_installment) {
                max_div = max_installment;
            }else{
                if(max_div > 12) {
                    max_div = 12;
                }
            }
            var limite = max_div;
            _.each( info_interest, function( key, value ) {
                if(count <= max_div){
                    value = info_interest[value];
                    if(value > 0){
                        var taxa = value/100;
                        if(type_interest == "compound"){
                            var pw = Math.pow((1 / (1 + taxa)), count);
                            var parcela = ((valor * taxa) / (1 - pw));
                        } else {
                            var parcela = ((valor*taxa)+valor) / count;
                        }
                        var total_parcelado = parcela*count;
                        var juros = value;
                        if(parcela > 5 && parcela > min_installment){
                            json_parcelas[count] = {
                                'parcela' : priceUtils.formatPrice(parcela),
                                'juros' : juros,
                            };
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(valor > 0 && count > 0){
                            json_parcelas[count] = {
                                    'parcela' : priceUtils.formatPrice((valor/count)),
                                    'juros' : 0,
                                };
                        }
                    }
                }
                count++;    
            });
            _.each( json_parcelas, function( key, value ) {
                if(key > limite){
                    delete json_parcelas[key];
                }
            });
            return json_parcelas;
        },        
        getInstallments: function (value_for_calc) {
            var temp = _.map(this.getInstall(value_for_calc), function (value, key) {
                if(value['juros'] == 0){
                    var info_interest = " sem juros";
                } else {
                    var info_interest = "*";
                }
                return {
                            'qty': key,
                            'installments': value['parcela'],
                            'info_interest': info_interest
                };

            });
            var newArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                if (temp[i].installments!='undefined' && temp[i].installments!=undefined) {
                    newArray.push(temp[i]);
                }
            }
            return newArray;
        }
     });
 });
```

html:

```
 <div class="price-box price-final_installment" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="<?php echo $block->getProductId(); ?>">
    <div class="block-installment-<?php echo $block->getProductId(); ?>" data-bind="scope: 'installment'">
        <input type="hidden" name="price-for-calc" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getCalcForPrice(); ?>" id="product-id-installment-<?php echo $block->getProductId(); ?>">
        <!-- ko if: display() -->

            <div class="installment-price" data-bind="foreach: maxInstallments">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'ou '"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: qty"></span>
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'x de '"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: installments"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: info_interest"></span>
            </div>

        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: display() -->
             <p class="empty-text" data-bind="text: $t('Você pode parcelar sua compra em até 12x.')"></p>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
 { ".block-installment-<?php echo $block->getProductId(); ?>": {
         "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
             "components": {
                 "installment": {
                    "component": "O2TI_Installment/js/view/installment",
                    "product_id": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getProductId() ?>",
                    "value_for_calc": "#product-id-installment-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getProductId() ?>",
                    "interest": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  json_encode($block->getInfoInterest()) ?>,
                    "type_interest": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getTypeInterest() ?>",
                    "limite_by_price": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getLimitByPlotPrice() ?>,
                    "limite_by_installment": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getLimitByPortionNumber() ?>
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: please provide a working fiddle or code because this is too much to review

Answer (score 0):

The solution was forwarded by @Sutil:

change:
data-bind="scope: 'installment'"
for:
data-bind="scope: 'installment-getProductId() ?>'"